# C++: IsWow64Process2: What valid WOW64 process architecture values can be returned via the pProcessMachine parameter?

Tags: c++, windows, wow64

[IsWow64Process2 docs (parameters section)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64process2#parameters) say the following:

> pProcessMachine
>
> On success, returns a pointer to an IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_* value. The value will be IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_UNKNOWN if the target process is not a WOW64 process; otherwise, it will identify the type of WoW process.

However, many of the [Image File Machine Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/image-file-machine-constants) would not apply, I would not think, because they are 64 bit, and only a 32 bit process can run under WOW64. Also, I am thinking, for Windows 10, the possible architectures can only be Intel (including AMD) or ARM based from this quote ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/running-32-bit-applications)):

> WOW64 is the x86 emulator that allows 32-bit Windows-based applications to run seamlessly on 64-bit Windows. This allows for 32-bit (x86) Windows applications to run seamlessly in 64-bit (x64) Windows, as well as for 32-bit (x86) and 32-bit (ARM) Windows applications to run seamlessly in 64-bit (ARM64) Windows.

Therefore, I am thinking only the following 32 bit machine type constants could possibly be returned via pProcessMachine if the process is indeed running under WOW64:

- IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386
- IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM

Related links:

- [IsWow64Process2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64process2)
- [Running 32 Bit Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/running-32-bit-applications)
- [GetNativeSystemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getnativesysteminfo)
- [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)

Am I correct in the above assumption and list of two possible architectures? Also, is there a place elsewhere in the Microsoft Windows docs (or any other blog, articles, books, etc.) that explains WOW64 and related topics more in-depth than the links I have shown above, perhaps explicitly addressing my question?

Comment: That function can only be used on a machine that boots Win10 or Server2016.  Makes it easy, no need to worry about encountering any old architecture.

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant - just to be explicit, those two constants I mention would indeed be the only possible values returned via the pProcessorMachine parameter? I have written some example code using IsWow64Process2 to determine host architecture, process architecture, and if running under WOW64 for the community and annotating it, so I want to be sure of my facts.